# DPDK EAL error when using IOVA-VA memory mode

Tags: kernel, driver, vmware, dpdk, iommu

I am running a VM inside a VMWARE server (vSphere).
My goal it to set up DPDK with two HW ports, and set up a virtio_user to interact with the kernel stack.
In another app I have it working but instead of virtio_user I am running KNI, it works in IOVA-PA mode.
I am looking to replace the KNI.

When I try to set up virtio_user port as in the doc:
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/virtio_user_as_exception_path.html#virtio-user-as-exception-path
I get a error it can't run in PA mode.

```
When I try to run as VA mode from a parameter, I get the following errors:
EAL: lib.eal log level changed from info to debug
EAL: Detected lcore 0 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 1 as core 0 on socket 0
EAL: Support maximum 128 logical core(s) by configuration.
EAL: Detected 2 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Checking presence of .so 'librte_eal.so.21.3'
EAL: Checking presence of .so 'librte_eal.so.21'
EAL: Checking presence of .so 'librte_eal.so'
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x7000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100000000 (size = 0x7000)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: DPAA Bus not present. Skipping.
EAL: VFIO PCI modules not loaded
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: IOMMU type 1 (Type 1) is supported
EAL: IOMMU type 7 (sPAPR) is not supported
EAL: IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU) is supported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x5b000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100007000 (size = 0x5b000)
EAL: Setting up physically contiguous memory...
EAL: Setting maximum number of open files to 1048576
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Creating 2 segment lists: n_segs:128 socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100062000 (size = 0x2000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated at socket 0, page size 0x100000kB
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2000000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x140000000 (size = 0x2000000000)
EAL: VA reserved for memseg list at 0x140000000, size 2000000000
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2140000000 (size = 0x2000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated at socket 0, page size 0x100000kB
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2000000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2180000000 (size = 0x2000000000)
EAL: VA reserved for memseg list at 0x2180000000, size 2000000000
EAL: TSC frequency is ~2350000 KHz
EAL: Main lcore 0 is ready (tid=7f8ad790ec00;cpuset=[0])
EAL: lcore 1 is ready (tid=7f8ad6907400;cpuset=[1])
EAL: Trying to obtain current memory policy.
EAL: Setting policy MPOL_PREFERRED for socket 0
EAL: Restoring previous memory policy: 0
EAL: request: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: Heap on socket 0 was expanded by 1024MB
EAL: PCI device 0000:0b:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL:   Expecting 'PA' IOVA mode but current mode is 'VA', not initializing
EAL: Requested device 0000:0b:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:13:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL:   Expecting 'PA' IOVA mode but current mode is 'VA', not initializing
EAL: Requested device 0000:13:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: Bus (pci) probe failed.
EAL: lib.telemetry log level changed from disabled to warning
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Error: number of ports must be even
EAL: request: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: Heap on socket 0 was shrunk by 1024MB
```

For some reason the HW ports won't setup. From what I understand net_vmxnet3 should work with VA mode.
I enabled I/OMUU for the VM.
The weird thing even when enabled, I still have the enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode flag on.
And because it's on the this:

```
dev_iova_mode = pci_device_iova_mode(dr, dev);
```

return PA mode, and it fails.

When I disable it by modifying /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode, I get another error.
The error is that it doesn't find a suitable IOMMU type:
Just putting the relevant message:

```
EAL: Heap on socket 0 was expanded by 1024MB
EAL: PCI device 0000:0b:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL: Set IOMMU type 1 (Type 1) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: Set IOMMU type 7 (sPAPR) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: Set IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: 0000:0b:00.0 failed to select IOMMU type
EAL: Requested device 0000:0b:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:13:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL: Set IOMMU type 1 (Type 1) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: Set IOMMU type 7 (sPAPR) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: Set IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU) failed, error 19 (No such device)
EAL: 0000:13:00.0 failed to select IOMMU type
EAL: Requested device 0000:13:00.0 cannot be used
```

I can see where it fails:

```
const struct vfio_iommu_type *
vfio_set_iommu_type(int vfio_container_fd)
{
    unsigned idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < RTE_DIM(iommu_types); idx++) {
        const struct vfio_iommu_type *t = &iommu_types[idx];

        int ret = ioctl(vfio_container_fd, VFIO_SET_IOMMU,
                t->type_id);
        if (!ret) {
            RTE_LOG(INFO, EAL, "Using IOMMU type %d (%s)\n",
                    t->type_id, t->name);
            return t;
        }
        /* not an error, there may be more supported IOMMU types */
        RTE_LOG(DEBUG, EAL, "Set IOMMU type %d (%s) failed, error "
                "%i (%s)\n", t->type_id, t->name, errno,
                strerror(errno));
    }
    /* if we didn't find a suitable IOMMU type, fail */
    return NULL;
}
```

The ioctl returns -1.

I tried many things.
Enabling/disabling IOMMU.
Modifying the enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode flag.
Running in PA mode.
Any help will be much appreciated.